# why does it count the number of "ratings" but not "Ratings"?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

```
private float ratingSum =0;
private void loadReviews() {
    reviewArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    ref.child(shopUid).child("Ratings")
            .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
                    long numberOfReviews = snapshot.getChildrenCount();
                    float rating = Float.parseFloat("" + snapshot.child("ratings").getValue());
                    ratingSum = ratingSum + rating;

                    ModelReview modelReview = snapshot.getValue(ModelReview.class);
                    reviewArrayList.add(modelReview);

                    adapterReview = new AdapterReview(ShopReviewsActivity.this, reviewArrayList);
                    reviewsRv.setAdapter(adapterReview);

                    float avgRating = ratingSum/numberOfReviews;

                    ratingsTv.setText(String.format("%.2f",avgRating)+"["+numberOfReviews+"]");
                    ratingBar.setRating(avgRating);
                }
```

I want it to count the number of reviewers (count the number of children in Ratings),
but it only counts the number of children of "ratings" and not of "Ratings"

[image]

Comment: To better understand, do you need to count the number of children within the "Ratings" node, is that correct?